# How can I render a page template from a queue job/console controller?

Tags: console

I'm trying to call `craft\web\View::renderPageTemplate` from within a console controller (also tried from a queue job), but running into all kinds of trouble:

E.g.

- Exception 'Twig_Error_Runtime' with message 'An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Session does not exist in a console request.").'

  - I discovered the this was due to `registerAssetFlashes`: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/279116ba4091edc67c92fcbbefc257bb4fe30335/src/web/View.php#L1418
- No plugins that register twig functions/filters work

Currently I'm doing:

```
$view = Craft::$app->getView();
$view->setTemplateMode($view::TEMPLATE_MODE_SITE);
$view->renderPageTemplate($template, $variables);
```

The end goal is to render a template, cache it, and send the html to a web service.

How can I do this without everything breaking?

…Or is there another way to do this, or should this be a feature request?

Answer (score 2):

Given that it's `craft\web\View.php` I think you're probably out of luck. Though it's only `registerAssetFlashes()` that seems to call `getSession()`, but I'm expecting more than just that may assume a frontend request. You could always ping a controller endpoint via Guzzle to return the Twig-rendered HTML to you though.

Comment: I thought about just making a web request via Guzzle but that isn't _really_ what I want in this case. This is not a publicly accessible template, I need to pass it `$variables`, and I want to cache the result (the latter I could still do via Guzzle).

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove every Twig function like `craft.app.getSession()` within your templates and use the

```
$view->renderTemplate($template, $variables);
```

function instead of

```
$view->renderPageTemplate($template, $variables);
```

Comment: I can do that, but still get errors with any Twig extension that is added by a plugin.